# Attack surface when no incoming port is open

Tags: vulnerability, nmap, ports, attack-vector

Let's assume that the only attack to be feared on a computer is one via the network in which the machine is embedded.

What options does an attacker have if the machine has no open incoming ports?

(For example: NMAP cannot find a service with an open port.)

Comment: Does this machine make outgoing connections to any other hosts on the network?

Comment: @mti2935 Yes, potentially it does. But both cases (yes and no) would be interesting for me.

Comment: It's not uncommon (especially in industrial settings) to have machines running OS's (e.g. Windows XP) that are past end of life still running on the network.  It can be done, if the right precautions are taken - i.e. use a hardware firewall in front of the machine to block all incoming connections, and only allow outgoing connections to trusted servers.  See https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/225338/safely-use-old-windows-xp-machine-in-business-network for more info.

Comment: Attack surface for what? Is it a system with no software on it, is it a machine which connects to the network, is it a machine which somehow reacts to what is happening on the network and in what way (like processing logs - see what happend with log4shell)? Open ports are not the only way to interact with the outside and thus having these as the only information is not sufficient to describe the attack surface.

Answer (score 1):

The question is much too broad, but here are a few ideas:

Layer 1:

- Attack via overvoltage destroying the network port.
- Attack via manipulated signal exploiting some vulnerability in the network port circuitry.

Layer 2:

- Denial of service by jamming the network circuit.
- Attack via manipulated packets exploiting some vulnerability in the network interface.
- ARP poisoning.

Layer 3:

- Malicious redirect of outgoing connections for denial of service or man in the middle attacks.

Layer 8:

- Tricking the administrator of the machine into opening an incoming port for the attacker.
- Tricking the administrator to install a trojanized program which opens an outgoing connection with a reverse shell.

Answer (score 0):

While the question is rather broad, it reflects the common thoughts of a beginner. My reading:

- the danger is the outside
- if nobody can enter from the outside my machine will be secure.

This is exactly what I thought (and did) for the first system I had to administer. And I only realized later how wrong I was...

Because the reality is often different.

Experimented administrators know that the most dangerous attacker lies between the chair and the keyboard. Many users want to customize their workstation, and "wow, why should I not install this {screensaver, animated wallpaper, tool} (pick your own), it's really cute". And while most tools coming from reputated sites are harmless, some may not be, specially if the origine is not controlled.

And some may contain backdoors. Imagine a nice tool that would display a random wallpaper everyday, or a funny greeting message at login time or randomly during the day. No surprise for the tool to use *outgoing* HTTP connections to pick new images/messages. But it could also during the same exchange upload system and network information, and download additional software. All that could later be used to get more control on that machine and even attack other machines on the local network.

That is the reason why best practices recommend:

- outgoing connections should be monitored and unlegimate traffic should be analyzed and blocked as soon as possible. Either blacklisting or whitelisting is acceptable, but black lists do require traffic analyzis on a regular base.
- any machine should be scanned for malwares on a regular base
- users should only have the minimal permissions required for their job and recieve a formation to IT security in par with their privileges. IMHO, this one is the hardest to efficiently obtain, because it implicitely assumes that the whole hierarchy is aware of IT security risks. And sadly enough this is not always true.

TL/DR: security is not that easy, and nothing can replace experiment. If you are a beginner (we all were...) never imagine you can do the right things on your own but blindly follow best practices even if you cannot currently understand the reason. You will later...